# How to upgrade to ubuntu 12.10 from 10.04(lucid)

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

currently am having two OS one is ubuntu 10.04 and windows 7. How to upgrade the ubuntu to 12.10. Kindly guide the installation without affecting windows 7 OS. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

You can update from Update Manager (it will not affect your Windows system), but i think will be better to backup your user data and make fresh install of 12.10.

Comment: The greater time/version difference, the more this advice is good.

Comment: You can't upgrade directly from 10.04 to 12.10 but you can upgrade from 10.04 to 12.04 then from 12.04 to 12.10.  However, I would advise a fresh install too.  A lot has changed between 10.04 and 12.10

Answer (score 0):

There's a utility built in for this.
Check this out: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/upgrade
Basically, open the update manager and click upgrade. You'll have to repeat this step until you get to 12.10

Honestly, it's probably best if you just back up your files and perform a clean install of 12.10.
During the setup, it will prompt you if you want to install it alongside Windows 7, so you shouldn't need to worry about messing Windows up.